# Drive api - How to navigate to my working directory?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am super new to using API's. I am trying to turn the drive api on and the final step is

*Click the file_download (Download JSON) button to the right of the client ID.
Move this file to your working directory and rename it client_secret.json.*

I already downloaded the file (JSON) and it's on my hard drive but I can't seem to navigate to my "working directory". Where is it? and how can I get to it from my "Api and services - Dashboard"

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the chapter 'Authentication with OAuth' of [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

Set the path to these credentials using `Google_Client::setAuthConfig:`

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('/path/to/client_credentials.json');
```

You can put the file whatever you want, but only set the path in the mentied place.